# How do I change my localhost application server from Apache httpd to the Tomcat that is built into ColdFusion 10?

Tags: apache, session, tomcat, coldfusion

Backstory: A couple of years ago my group changed the server on which coldfusion runs to Apache instead of IIS. I changed my dev environment to run CF on Apache httpd and everything was fine. Later we changed the session variables to j2ee, but I have never been able to get j2ee to work on dev so I am still using regular session variables on dev. Lately I am getting session persistence failure on test but I can't reproduce on dev. In looking for differences in CF server settings between test and dev I discovered that test is running on Tomcat while dev is running on Apache httpd.

My problem real problem is how to get j2ee session vars to work on dev. My question right now is how do I change my server from Apache httpd to the Tomcat that is built in with CF 10? Is there a way to do this without starting over with a fresh install of CF 10 as those are the only instructions I can find?

System: Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

IIS and Apache are not (for Coldfusion, anyway) application servers. They are your front-end web servers. Your 'application server' in this setup is the software running the "application" of Coldfusion via servlets, and that's Tomcat.

While it is possible to use CF's builtin Tomcat server as your front-end web server, it isn't advisable, and it's almost certainly got nothing to do with your problem. Apache is more than capable of doing what you need and a problem with J2EE session variables is going to be related either to your JVM (are you using more-or-less the same version as your production server?) or to Tomcat itself.

Think about how J2EE sessions work. A request comes in and hits your front-end server (httpd), which, presumabl through mod_proxy or mod_jk, hands that connection over to Tomcat. Until this happens, that your system is even running a JVM isn't relevant -- neither Apache nor IIS care about Java. I wouldn't go so far as to say that it's impossible for an Apache problem to be monkeying with your session variables, but it would be pretty low on my list of suspects.

Once Tomcat (and then CF) get involved, then your JVM is doing all the work, so that's where I'd look. I'd also have a look at CF logs and Tomcat logs.

To properly answer your question, though, if you want to remove Apache from the loop, you're looking at Tomcat's server.xml and web.xml in /cfusion/runtime/conf - you'd need it running on port 80 (or else reconfigure Apache to just pass all requests to Tomcat instead of only CFML, but that doesn't really do what you asked about since Apache is still involved). You'd also have to reproduce your entire Apache configuration in Tomcat, which I've never done and wouldn't recommend, but that's the direction you'd need to investigate.

Much better to work on solving your session problem. Killing Apache is just collateral damage here.